# Assistance writing a MeanMedDiff function

Tags: r, function, vector

I'm trying to write a MeanMedDiff function in R that returns the absolute difference between the mean and median of a vector. Here's what I've come up with, but I'm getting an error. Any ideas on my mistake?

```
MeanMedDiff <- function(lst){
  median <- median(lst)
  mean <- mean(lst)
  diff <- mean-median
  abs(diff)
  }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the input and error message. Thank you.

Comment: Also ``lst`` is use as the name of a certain data structure, so changing `lst`` to something like ``my_lst`` will help.

Comment: This seems to work fine

Comment: Your input could be a `list` instead of `vector` that triggered the error, try `MeanMedDiff(unlist(yourlst))` or it may not be a `numeric` vector

Answer (score 0):

```
MeanMedDiff <- function(lst){
  if(is.vector(lst)) {
      abs(median(lst)-mean(lst))
     }
  if(is.list(lst)) {
      abs(median(unlist(lst))-mean(unlist(lst)))
     }
  }
```